# Django model DateField format in modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, date, datefield

I'm trying to make a `modelform_factory` for my model named `Book` but the `DateField` is behaving strangely.

```
class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   date = models.DateField(max_length = 50)
```

I have a function in my `views` that returns this:

```
modelform = modelformset_factory(Book, fields = (
    'name',
    'date',
),
can_delete=True,
widgets = {
    'date': forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
})
```

In my `template` this modelform will render with a datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

So far so good, and everything is working as expected to this point. But when I post my form to my view again, and save the modelformset, the `dd/mm/yyyy` date is wrongly converted to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = modelform(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Book.objects.filter(name=book))

    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save() # This first deletes all instances that are checked for deletion
        f = formset.save(commit=False) # This filters the formset to only include filled in forms
        for form in f:
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse("success")
```

Does someone has any clue how I can format this `dd/mm/yyyy` date to correctly enter my database?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reformat the date to match what the field requires (yyyy-mm-dd). You'll need to change the value via jQuery after using the datapicker tool which is using the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Somthing like:

```
  $("#dateField").on('change', function(){
      var arr = $("#dateField").val().split("/");
      var newDate = arr[2]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"+arr[0];
      $("#dateField").val(newDate);
  });
```

Then, you'll need to parse that string to a date type in your view before saving it with parse_date:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = request.POST['dateField']
pDate= parse_date(date)
form.date = pDate
form.save()
```

In the source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateField
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse

Comment: First of all, thank you for you help! This would indeed work, but then my datepicker is displaying the value as yyyy-mm-dd. I would like to display the date in my front end as dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: You could change the event from .on(‘change’...  to change the value upon submission .submit(function(e){ e.prevent default;....